# Is it possible to export delivery pipeline settings?

Tags: ibm-cloud, devops-services

I would like to use the same bluemix delivery pipeline for several apps. Could I export its settings to some template?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

From the doc found [here](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/develop/sharetextpipelines.html),

> Section: GENERATING A YAML FILE FROM A PIPELINE
>   
> You can generate a YAML file from a pipeline.
>   
> Generate the file from an existing pipeline with a URL in this format:
>
> ```
> http(s)://<DevOps Services domain>/pipeline/user/project/yaml
> ```
>
> This call does not require an accept header. You can use this call from a browser.

**Note**: For safety reasons, secure-stage environment property values are omitted from generated pipeline YAML files.

To reuse this downloaded template, per the link shared above - simply create a **.bluemix** folder at the root of your other code project folders and place this template file within this .bluemix folder.  The file should be named as **pipeline.yml**

Comment: Sanjay, do you know the current answer to this question? Is it still possible to export them?

Answer (score 0):

How to do it nowadays (March 2020)

To export a pipeline simple add `/yaml`to pipeline url. example:

From:

`https://cloud.ibm.com/devops/pipelines/<pipeline-guid>?env_id=<ibm_cloud_region>`

To:

`https://cloud.ibm.com/devops/pipelines/<pipeline-guid>/yaml?env_id=<ibm_cloud_region>`

Download the file and store it as `pipeline.yml`. Put it inside `.bluemix` folder in the root of your project as @Sanjay.Joshi said.